# Cannot use parametrization on "set variable = ?" statement but hardcoding works

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I want to change the parameter `statement_timeout` after establishing a JDBC connection. Therefore I have the following code:

```
PreparedStatement statement = _connection.prepareStatement("set statement_timeout = ?");
statement.setInt(1, (int) _statementTimeout);
statement.execute();
```

But on `execute()` this results in a SQL exception clearly stating that I have an error in the syntax at my question mark.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
  Position: 25
```

I tried searching for this problem but couldn't find any right answers. The pages thinks I refer to the `SET` of an `UPDATE`-clause.

My question is simple, why is parametrization not working? If I hardcode the value, e.g.

`prepareStatement(String.format("set statement_timeout = %s", _statementTimeout))`

everything works fine and as expected. Or is it simply wrong to use parametrization on setting variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the equivalent [function call](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET) should work:

```
prepareStatement("select set_config('statement_timeout', ?, false)");
statement.setString(1, Integer.toString(_statementTimeout));
statement.execute();
```

Note that you need to pass the value as a String as the function's signature is `(text, text, boolean)`

Comment: While this works fine (thanks for the solution), I assume this is bound to PostgreSQL. So if I have a MySQL or MSSQL database, executing this will throw an exception, right?

Comment: `SET statement_timeout = ...` is already Postgres specific. If you want a cross-database solution you should use `Statement.setQueryTimeout()` - but that needs to be done for each Statement instance.